# How to sort the the sql table considering Month and Year Column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a year column that contains things string value like 2015,2014, 2013, 2012, etc. A month column that displays string value like 1, 2,3,...12. I need to run a select that sort the table considering the both Year and month column. Can anyone provide some input? Is the any system procedures to do it easily.
For Ex.-

```
 Month Year
    12    2015
    11    2015  
    10    2015
    9     2015
    .      .
    .      .   
    .      .
    1     2015
```

I want the output based on the Year and Month descending Order.

Comment: Why do you use string types for numbers? and why don't you change it?

Comment: For mysql : `order by (year + 0) desc, (month + 0) desc` .

Comment: SQL Server (assuming month stored as text): `...ORDER BY CAST([Month] AS INT) DESC, [Year] DESC;`.  As you can see SQL Server and MySQL often require different approaches.  That's one reason why it's recommended you don't double tag questions.  Please can you remove whichever product you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server below query will work.
you just need to concatenate the month and date columns

```
select * from Table order by cast([month] + '/1/' + [year] as date) desc
```

If you are using mysql then below query will work.

```
select * from Table order by STR_TO_DATE(( CONCAT(month,'/1/',year)),'%c/%e/%Y %H:%i') desc
```